# Pure CSS: Multiple on-hover functions are not working

Tags: css, hover

Can anyone tell me why is this not working? I want when I hover over the box, it opens up (from 10px wide to 300px wide) and displays the picture (within the box).

The box and content work independently, but when I put them together in the on-hover they clash.

```
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled 1</title>

 <style type="text/css">
 .BOX {
     width: 10px;
     height: 600px;
     background: rgba(55, 55, 55, .8);
     -webkit-transition-property: width; /* Safari */
     -webkit-transition-duration: 4s; /* Safari */
     -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
     transition-property: width;
     transition-duration: 2s;
     transition-delay: 0s;
     position: absolute;
     z-index:-1;
 }

 .PICTURE {
     position: absolute;
     z-index:1;
     top: 100px;
     left:100px;
        visibility:hidden;
 }

  .BOX:hover  + .PICTURE {
     visibility:visible;
        width: 300px;       
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="BOX"></div>
 <div class="PICTURE" style="width: 99px; height: 150px;"><img 
 src="pic.jpg"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: It's probably because your `<style>` is written before the `<div>` is defined. Change the priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some jquery, it's much easier. Maybe this will help you: jsfiddle.net/sr6Lsour/

Comment: Triied both.. Can anyone copy and paste a working script of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
.BOX:hover  + .PICTURE {
```

is only for the picture, you need to use

```
.BOX:hover,.BOX:hover  + .PICTURE {
```

[more information](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/adjacent-sibling/) on the +